# Hibernate Spring: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property doesn't create generate tables doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate. I configure Hibernate using configuration Java class:

**DbConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "testproject", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
 public class DbConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("testproject");

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testproject");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("mypass");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("testproject");
        //getHibernateProperties method is a private method

        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");

        System.out.println();
        // other properties
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

The auto-creation of tables is configured inside `getHibernateProperties` method:

```
hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");
```

However it doesn't seem to work: after I deploy server and try to insert an entity I get an error and the database has no tables.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @MinarMahmund `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` - it's not the point here - that error happens because the tables have not been created. The question is about how to get Hibernate to auto-create tables

Comment: What does your `org.hibernate.SQL` logger log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is of type [`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.Hibernate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties.Hibernate.html) which is from ***Spring Boot***. But you are using ***Spring MVC***.

use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` instead.

**Further Reading**

- [*Metadata Format*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-format) in Spring Boot Reference

This is the properties code that works:

```
   @Bean
    private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProperties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
```